# LibGDX Копия BitmapFont из AssetManager

Tags: java, libgdx

Есть статичная переменная `manager`, через неё получаю все нужные мне ресурсы, шрифт генерируется из `.ttf` с помощью расширения.

```
    FileHandleResolver resolver=new InternalFileHandleResolver();
    FreeTypeFontGeneratorLoader gener=new FreeTypeFontGeneratorLoader(resolver);
    manager.setLoader(FreeTypeFontGenerator.class, gener);
    manager.setLoader(BitmapFont.class, ".ttf", new FreetypeFontLoader(resolver));
    FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter fnt=new FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter();
    fnt.fontFileName=baseFont;
    fnt.fontParameters.size=76;
    fnt.fontParameters.characters=fnt.fontParameters.characters+russian;
    manager.load(baseFont, BitmapFont.class, fnt);
```

Далее пытаюсь получить копию этого шрифта для дальнейших манипуляций с помощью функции

```
public static BitmapFont getFont(){
    BitmapFont f=manager.get(NOUAssets.baseFont);
    BitmapFont fnt=new BitmapFont(f.getData(), f.getRegion(), false);
    fnt.setUseIntegerPositions(false);
    fnt.getData().setScale(.1f);
    fnt.getData().markupEnabled=true;
    return fnt;
}
```

Как результат я получаю ссылку на тот шрифт который я загрузил в `AssetManager`, т.к. после изменения полученного через `getFont()` шрифта меняется он везде...
Где я делаю что-то не так?